# how to add a link to Kendo TreeList

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
                var mdl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FacilityList));

                var ds = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                    data: mdl,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "ClientOrganizationId",
                            fields: {
                                parentId: { field: "ParentOrganizationId",  nullable: true },
                                ClientOrganizationId: { field: "ClientOrganizationId", type: "number" },
                                Name: { field: "Name"},
                                Street: { field: "Street" },
                                City: { field: "City" },
                                State: { field: "State" },
                                ZipCode: { field: "Zipcode" }
                            },
                            expanded: true
                        }
                    }});

                $("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
                    dataSource: ds,
                    selectable: true,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "Name", title: "Organization Name"},
                        { field: "Contracted", title: "Contracted"},
                        { field: "ClientOrganizationId", title: "Id"},
                        { field: "Street", title: "Street"},
                        { field: "City", title: "City" },
                        { field: "State", title: "State" },
                        { field: "ZipCode", title: "ZipCode"}]});
```

How would I add another column that contains an actionlink to the "Home" controller's "Update" action passing the ClientOrganizationId as a parameter?

I want the Update action to be something like this

```
    public ActionResult Update(int Id)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a column template; basically something like:

```
{ 
  field: "ClientOrganizationId", 
  title: "Id link", 
  template: "<a href='/Home/Update/#= ClientOrganizationId #'>" + 
            "link me to id: #= ClientOrganizationId # </a>"
},
```

I.e. fill in whatever is needed to call the Update action while writing the id value with

`#= ClientOrganizationId` #

(I don't remember the link semantics offhand, so the href part may be very wrong)

Comment: Works in kendo-templates too (as one would expect). Thanks!